# M1/M2 | Extensions - best practices for naming, versioning, author

Tags: extensions, best-practice

was wondering what is the best practice for ...

- naming an extentsion?
- where to put the copyright holders /authors name?
- versioning (`major.minor.patch` maybe) of extensions

I guess there must be conventions or bet practices for this (M1 / M2) but couldn't really find anything thus far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find plenty of resources online but i would suggest Dev Docs is right place to start with [Create new module](https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/).

You will get some insight which files are needed why needed and where these have to be placed while developing a module.

Comment: thx @naveed. Will take a peep into that. Wondering why it's using term 'module' rather then extension. Is this just sloppy or is there any logical dependency between a 'Module' and an 'Extention' in Magento?

Comment: seems basically __VendorName_ExtensionName__ was a common naming scheme. Are hyphens allowed in the Extension name (like __VendorName_extension-name__ i.e.)? That would make things better readable in git repositories (which aren't using Capitals).