# custom extensions - are hyphens allowed in the Extension name?

Tags: magento2, extensions, best-practice, repository, naming-convention

This is a follow up on the Magento 2 Extension naming convention question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241502/m1-m2-extensions-best-practices-for-naming-versioning-author/241504#241504).

I've learned thus far that you need

- a **Vendor Name**
- an **Extension (or Module) name**
- **a combination of both** like `Vendor_ExtensionName` (to be used in a `~/etc/module.xml` file).

Now something like `ExtensionName` (Capitals of both terms making it more readable) does not play all too nice in a git repository (which many may be using for development) so my question is:

**Is it ok to use hyphens to separate words in the Extension name** like `Vendor_My-Extension` (which makes a `vendor_my-extension` git repository) **or does that run contrary to best coding practices?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's allowed by default, only "_" is not allowed inside extensions or modules name because Magento 1.9 replace "_" to "/" when build path to files while looking files.

Using hyphens bad practice in Magento development, you should use CamelCase instead. This is a code standard for that framework.

Comment: thnks @SergeYudin for clarifying